# how to pause javascript function on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, hover

i have an image slider made using javascript, as there are multiple images in the slide i want to pause the function if the user hovers on the slide and then play it back when user stops hovering, my code is like below:

```js
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.slideshow-container');

  for (let i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
    const slides = containers[i].getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    const active_slide = containers[i].querySelector('.active');
    let slideIndex = [...active_slide.parentNode.children].indexOf(active_slide) + 1;

    active_slide.classList.remove('active');
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
      slideIndex = 1
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.add('active');
  }
  setTimeout(showSlides, 4000);
}
```

```css
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.mySlides.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-10 slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fades active">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 12</div>
    <img src="fb1.jpg" alt="Image 1">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fades">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 12</div>
    <img src="fb2.jpg" alt="Image 2">
  </div>
  ....
</div>
```

can anyone please tell me how to accomplish this , thanks in advance

Comment: Add a variable to acts as a flag. Set it on hover, unset it on un-hover. Skip the activity in your `showSlides` function if the variable is set.

Comment: what Ouroborus actually mean is to set a variable with a boolean (true/false) and that variable must change to true/false depending if you hover or not. Than you sue an ìf-statement` or a `conditional ternary operator` to run a function or not depending on the boolean variable.

Comment: @tacoshy can u please show as a sample if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified the issue with a different code, showing how to solve the problem.

As said in the comments, you need just a boolean variable that acts as a flag. Then you use an `if-statement` to check if the flag/variable is set to true or false which then decides if the function within the setInterval/setTimeout executes or not:

```js
//boolean variable acting as flag
var pause = false;

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function counter() {
  let i = 2;
  setInterval(function() {
    //checks if the function should be "paused" or not
    if (pause === false) {
      document.querySelector('.counter').textContent = i;
      i++;
    }
  }, 1000);
})

var hover_ele = document.querySelector('.pause');

//pauses the intervall
hover_ele.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  pause = true;
})

//stops the intervall
hover_ele.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  pause = false;
})
```

```css
/* for demo purposes only */
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.counter {
  font-size: 3em;
}

.pause {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="counter">1</div>
<div class="pause"> Hover me to pause the counter </div>
```